# Axios post request is processed twice by the node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have an issue with my backend code which executes a request from Axios twice. I am using react in the frontend and I am sending a simple post request to the backend when the page loads. Please see the code below for the Axios post request to the server.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    loadPopularDest();
  }, [latlong]);
const loadPopularDest = async () => {
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/nearbyplaces", { ll: latlong })
      .then(async (res) => {
        setDestination(res.data);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(destination);     
          setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

and my backend code is

```
router.route("/nearbyplaces").post(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.ll);
  const data = [];
  const placeDetail = [];
  await axios
    .get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json", {
      params: {
        key: process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY,
        location: req.body.ll,
        radius: 20000,
        keyword: "popular destinations near me",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(1, "for loop starts here");
      response.data.results.forEach((value, i) => {
        if (!value.hasOwnProperty("photos")) {
          data.push({
            name: value.name,
            photoUrl: "N/A",
            address: value.formatted_address,
            location: value.geometry.location,
            rating: value.rating,
            status: value.business_status,
            tags: value.types,
            placeId: value.place_id,
          });
        } else {
          data.push({
            name: value.name,
            photoUrl: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=800&photoreference=${value.photos[0].photo_reference}&key=${process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY}`,
            address: value.formatted_address,
            location: value.geometry.location,
            rating: value.rating,
            status: value.business_status,
            tags: value.types,
            placeId: value.place_id,
          });
        }
      });
      console.log(1, "for loop ends here");
    })
    .then(async () => {
      console.log(2, "for loop starts here");
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        await axios
          .get(
            `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${data[i].placeId}&fields=name,rating,url,website,formatted_phone_number&key=${process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY}`
          )
          .then((response) => {
            placeDetail.push(response.data.result);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.response.data);
          });
      }
      console.log(2, "for loop ends here");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response);
    });
  console.log(3, "map starts here");
  data.map((value, index) => {
    return (value["place_details"] = placeDetail[index]);
  });
  console.log(3, "map ends here");
  console.log(5, data[0]);
  res.send(data);
});
```

When the request is sent to the server, the `console.log(5, data[0]);` just above the `res.send(data)` returns `undefined` and none of the for loops are executed at first so the `loop starts here` and `loop ends here` (in the screenshot) is printed in the console log immediately. Then it runs for the second time which returns the expected results. All this is happening for one single post request sent from the frontend. I have added a screenshot of my console log below. Please have a look at it. The log inside the blue color box is executed straight away it doesn't wait for anything and The red box is the actual output that I receive when it runs again for no reason.
[image: screen shot of my console log]

I am not sure where I am wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix async/await with .then and .catch .First of all, you should change this.

You can also create this function inside the useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {

  async function loadPopularDest() {
  
    try {
     const response = await axios
       .post("http://localhost:5000/nearbyplaces", { ll: latlong })
      
      setDestination(response.data);
      setLoading(false)
     
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
   
  }

    loadPopularDest();

  }, [latlong]);
```

Comment: Hi @gabriel Tiso, It is not working and It gives the same output as before. Also, I tried without async and await in .then block but it gives me the same output. Moreover, you have mentioned that I can't mix async and await, is there any other way to achieve this? please let me know and in the meantime, I will try to use Promises and see how that works.